# Unpermitted parameter: locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, permissions, activeadmin

I have some trouble with "locale" in my Rails App with ActiveAdmin after logging. How can i permit params for locale?

```
Started GET "/admin?locale=ru" for ::1 at 2015-02-25 23:05:19 +0100
Processing by Admin::DashboardController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"ru"}
  AdminUser Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Unpermitted parameter: locale
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin?locale=ru
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

my application_controller.rb

```
   before_filter :set_locale

   def set_locale
     I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
   end

   def default_url_options(options={})
     { :locale => I18n.locale }
   end
```

config/application.rb

```
 config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]

    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    #config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
   config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = true
    config.i18n.default_locale = :ru
```

app/admin/admin_user.rb

```
 permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role, :locale
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define permitted_params in your active admin controller

Here is my fix:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Model do
  controller do
    def permitted_params
      params.permit(:utf8, :_method, :authenticity_token, :locale, :commit, :id,
        model: [:description, :price, :name, :limit, :shipping, :slug, :project_id]
      )
    end
  end
end
```

'Model' is the name of your model and do not forget to include foreign params :utf8, :_method, :authenticity_token